# Installing OsmAnd-ios, missing perl in PATH

Tags: git, perl, cmake

I am trying to install OsmAnd-ios project from Github page https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-ios

I did something like this:

- `git clone https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-ios.git`
- `repo init -u https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-manifest -m readonly.xml`
- `cd OsmAnd-ios`
- `git clone https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-core.git`
- rename the folder `OsmAnd-core` to `core`
- `git clone https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-build.git`
- rename the folder `OsmAnd-build` to `build`
- open `./prepare.sh` and update line `ROOT="$SRCLOC/../"` to `ROOT="$SRCLOC/"`
- run command `./prepare.sh`

In my case this leads to the following error:

```
DEFAULT_LIBDIRS="/lib
/usr/lib"

You need perl in your PATH to make a build from GIT.
Cannot proceed.
Failed to configure 'qtbase-ios' for 'ios.simulator.clang.static', aborting...
CMake Error at utils/common.cmake:58 (message):
  Failed to build upstream "/Users/alessandro/Desktop/XCodeProjects/OsmAnd-ios/build/../core/externals/qtbase-ios" for ios/clang/fat: 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qt.cmake:34 (build_upstream_ex)
  CMakeLists.txt:240 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/alessandro/Desktop/XCodeProjects/OsmAnd-ios/baked/fat-ios-clang.xcode/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Failed to bake project files 'fat-ios-clang.xcode' (1)
Failed to generate project for XCode, aborting...
```

I think my perl is properly installed, I added it to the `$PATH` using the command

`export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"`, that because the command `whereis perl` returned `/usr/bin/perl`

UPDATE #1

This is a full log of the `./prepare.sh` command:

```
cli-10-105-4-243:OsmAnd-ios alessandro$ ./prepare.sh 
Updating dependencies via CocoaPods
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/alessandro/.cocoapods/repos/master fetch origin
  --progress
  remote: Enumerating objects: 3121, done.        
  remote: Counting objects: 100% (3121/3121), done.        
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2513/2513), done.        
  remote: Total 2605 (delta 1785), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0        
  Receiving objects: 100% (2605/2605), 272.25 KiB | 1.51 MiB/s, done.
  Resolving deltas: 100% (1785/1785), completed with 461 local objects.
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
     d46887f228d..eecdebc1214  master     -> origin/master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/alessandro/.cocoapods/repos/master rev-parse --abbrev-ref
  HEAD
  master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/alessandro/.cocoapods/repos/master reset --hard
  origin/master
  HEAD is now at eecdebc1214 [Add] DryKline 0.1.3

CocoaPods 1.8.0.beta.2 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.8.0.beta.2

Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `QuickDialog` from `https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog.git`
Downloading dependencies
Using AFDownloadRequestOperation (2.0.1)
Using AFNetworking (2.5.4)
Using BRCybertron (1.1.1)
Using CocoaSecurity (1.2.4)
Using DACircularProgress (2.2.0)
Using FFCircularProgressView (0.5)
Using Firebase (4.0.4)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.2)
Using FirebaseCore (4.0.4)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.10)
Using FormatterKit (1.8.2)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.2.1)
Using HTAutocompleteTextField (1.3.2)
Using JASidePanels (1.3.2)
Using MBProgressHUD (0.9.2)
Using MDFInternationalization (2.0.0)
Using MaterialComponents (84.0.0)
Installing QuickDialog 1.0.2
Using Reachability (3.1.1)
Using RegexKitLite (4.0)
Using SWTableViewCell (0.3.7)
Using TPKeyboardAvoiding (1.2.11)
Using UIActionSheet-Blocks (1.0.1)
Using UIAlertView-Blocks (1.0)
Using nanopb (0.3.901)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 20 dependencies from the Podfile and 25 total pods installed.

[!] `xcodeproj` was renamed to `project`. Please update your Podfile accordingly.
Baking project files for cross-platform target 'fat-ios-clang'
Baking project files 'fat-ios-clang.xcode'
Possibly baked dir /Users/alessandro/Desktop/XCodeProjects/OsmAnd-ios/build/utils/../../baked/fat-ios-clang.xcode needs to be deleted.
CMake Deprecation Warning at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeForceCompiler.cmake:79 (message):
  The CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER macro is deprecated.  Instead just set
  CMAKE_C_COMPILER and allow CMake to identify the compiler.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  targets/fat-ios-clang.cmake:11 (CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER)
  /Users/alessandro/Desktop/XCodeProjects/OsmAnd-ios/baked/fat-ios-clang.xcode/CMakeFiles/3.6.2/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (project)


CMake Deprecation Warning at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeForceCompiler.cmake:93 (message):
  The CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER macro is deprecated.  Instead just set
  CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER and allow CMake to identify the compiler.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  targets/fat-ios-clang.cmake:12 (CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER)
  /Users/alessandro/Desktop/XCodeProjects/OsmAnd-ios/baked/fat-ios-clang.xcode/CMakeFiles/3.6.2/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (project)


System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/iOS to use this system, please send your config file to cmake@www.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
Your CMakeCache.txt file was copied to CopyOfCMakeCache.txt. Please send that file to cmake@www.cmake.org.
Using cross-platform target settings from toolchain file 'targets/fat-ios-clang.cmake'
CMAKE_TARGET_OS = ios
CMAKE_TARGET_CPU_ARCH = fat
CMAKE_TARGET_CPU_ARCH_FAMILY = fat
CMAKE_SHARED_LIBS_ALLOWED_ON_TARGET = FALSE
CMAKE_STATIC_LIBS_ALLOWED_ON_TARGET = TRUE
CMAKE_COMPILER_FAMILY = clang
OSMAND_OUTPUT_ROOT = /Users/alessandro/Desktop/XCodeProjects/OsmAnd-ios/build/../binaries/ios.clang$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS =  -fvisibility=hidden
CMAKE_C_FLAGS =  -fvisibility=hidden
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS =  -std=c++11 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
Going to build embedded Qt for ios/clang

This is the Qt Open Source Edition.

You are licensed to use this software under the terms of
the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) versions 3.
You are also licensed to use this software under the terms of
the GNU General Public License (GPL) versions 2.

You have already accepted the terms of the Open Source license.

./configure: line 3323: [: too many arguments
./configure: line 3323: [: too many arguments
DEFAULT_INCDIRS="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.4.sdk/usr/include
"
DEFAULT_LIBDIRS="/lib
/usr/lib"

You need perl in your PATH to make a build from GIT.
Cannot proceed.
Failed to configure 'qtbase-ios' for 'ios.simulator.clang.static', aborting...
CMake Error at utils/common.cmake:58 (message):
  Failed to build upstream "/Users/alessandro/Desktop/XCodeProjects/OsmAnd-ios/build/../core/externals/qtbase-ios" for ios/clang/fat: 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qt.cmake:34 (build_upstream_ex)
  CMakeLists.txt:240 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/alessandro/Desktop/XCodeProjects/OsmAnd-ios/baked/fat-ios-clang.xcode/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Failed to bake project files 'fat-ios-clang.xcode' (1)
Failed to generate project for XCode, aborting...
```

The Command `perl -V:'(site)?bin'` output is :

```
bin='/usr/bin';
sitebin='/usr/local/bin';
```

I have found the file which is giving me the error, it is located in:
⁨⁨core⁩ ▸ ⁨externals⁩ ▸ ⁨qtbase-ios⁩ ▸ ⁨upstream.patched⁩ and it's named configure

I added this lines:

```
echo "PATH variable: $PATH"
echo "Perl error path: $relpath/.git"
echo "if [ -z PERL ] -> $PERL"
```

And getting this output

```
PATH variable: /usr/bin:/usr/bin/perl:/usr/bin/perl:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local:/usr:/usr/:/usr/bin/perl:/usr/bin/perl:/Users/alessandro/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/alessandro/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:x/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin/perl:/opt/X11/bin

Perl error path: /Users/alessandro/Desktop/XCodeProjects/OsmAnd-ios/core/externals/qtbase-ios/upstream.patched.ios.simulator.clang.static/.git

if [ -z PERL ] ->
```

So $PERL is empty.

Comment: hmmm, the phrase `You need perl in your PATH` doesn't appear in any of the three repos you mentioned. Could you please narrow down the source of the message? Without knowing what check leads to the message, we can't really help you satisfy it.

Comment: It might help to make sure that both of the dirs output by `perl -V:'(site)?bin'` are in the PATH.

Comment: The line feed in `DEFAULT_LIBDIRS="/lib
/usr/lib"` is suspicious

Comment: Might be from Qt's installer, which has a script named [`configure`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/configure) which includes [this](https://pastebin.com/gQRC6try). You might want to modify that file to add debugging information. What does it see for `$PATH`? What does `$WHICH perl` output and is its error code?

Comment: I could add a full log of the whole process. I'll update the post in order to answer your questions.